# docker-compose up permission denied on sh file

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3" services:\   local_db:
    build:
      context: mssql-data
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ~/Documents/rfg/temp
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "D0ckerDev"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

When I run docker-compose up I get the following error:

```
local_db_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: line 5: /scripts/seed-data.sh: Permission denied
docker_local_db_1 exited with code 126
```

Where entry point is:

```
#start SQL Server in the background
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &

# start the seed data script 
/scripts/seed-data.sh
```

Where seed-data.sh was:

```
sleep 15s cd /scripts

if [ -f /var/opt/mssql/data/initialized ]; then
    sleep infinity
    fi sleep 15s /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i setup.sql

touch /var/opt/mssql/data/initialized sleep infinity
```

and entrypoint.sh:

```
#start SQL Server in the background
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &

# start the seed data script 
/scripts/seed-data.sh
```

and the Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

COPY . /scripts

CMD chmod 755 /scripts/*
CMD chmod 755 /scripts/seed-data.sh

CMD /bin/bash /scripts/entrypoint.sh
```

The above works fine in Windows but on MacOS I get th epermission denied error above..

Comment: That's not a valid Dockerfile. You can only have one `CMD` statement, which controls what Docker will run when you start the container. If you need to execute multiple commands when the container starts up, just use `CMD /bin/bash /scripts/entrypoint.sh` and put the rest of the commands in `entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: ah thanks for the information, I am very new to docker. However I just realised that docker seemed to be caching the old Dockerfiles and when I copied them into a new folder everything worked, including the multiple CMDs.

Either way I only was able to get it working by following your answer so I'm sure by some lucky accident this dockerfile worked and the next step is to make it valid following your answer on setting the chmod.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set the correct permissions on your `seed-data.sh` script.  You could just call it like this:

```
sh /scripts/seed-data.sh
```

Or you can make sure all your scripts are executable first:

```
chmod 755 /scripts/*
/scripts/seed-data.sh
```

Comment: Your suggestions are great but unfortunately I just realised my question wasn't complete, the files in seed-data.sh are being executed inside the docker image where the files are copied into a scripts folder and executed.

I tired chmod 755ing the scripts inside the dockerfile (see updated question) but sadly it didn't help...